# becomeFirstResponder not show keyboard in ios 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I tried to show a keyboard on after loading screen like this:

```
 -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
     tf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
     tf.text = @"test";

    [self.view addSubview:tf]; 
    if([tf canBecomeFirstResponder]){
        [tf becomeFirstResponder]; // surely this line is called          
     }
 }
```

**This code works on ios 8,9,10 but not 11**. I'm not sure why the keyboard isn't show automatically on ios 11 while text field is focusing (has cursor). 
And in this case, keyboard's notification isn't called:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    DLog(@"Keyboard Height: %f Width: %f", kbSize.height, kbSize.width);
 }
```

I even try this:

```
[tf performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

but still not work.

**I have to click on text field to bring up the keyboard**.
Is there anything update from Apple which I don't know?

**Update**: it looks like there is something wrong with my project or all my view controllers because I can't make the keyboard showing on all screens. But when I create new project with above code, it can work well.
Here is one of the problem:

[image]

As you can see, I **have to click on the textfield to show the keyboard**, and **from the second time, it can work properly**. And this issue only happended on ios 11 (both simulator & device) 
 
Here is the code for search field above:

```
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 215, 30)];
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter text to search";
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
    textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.navigationBar
                  duration:0.55f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    self.navigationItem.titleView = textField;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
                }];
```

I wonder is there anything cause conflict keyboard?

Comment: You are running your code on simulator ?? If yes toggle hardware keyboard by selecting simulator and then hit command+shift+k

Comment: Why are you adding a text field in the `viewDidAppear` method? That can be called many times. You should add the text field in `viewDidLoad`. You can still make it the first responder in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I test on both device & simulator. I already use toggle keyboard. If I click on the textfield by hand, keyboard can show correctly, but I want to show automatically after screen is loaded

Comment: @rmaddy I know, this only way I try to test, to make sure screen is loaded. I just add view in viewdidload and set first responder in viewDidAppear as you said, but still not work, keyboard didn't show up

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @john07 I dont know, but it can be fixed by showing a UIAlertView, you can check it in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48518087/719212

Comment: @R4   thanx but i resolved problem. I have 2 windows in my app and set makeKeyAndVisible to another window. That ref helped me
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1813/_index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really weird, because this issue can be fixed after showing a `UIAlertView`
So when I try to add a `UIAlertView` with loading indicator (and auto dimiss after few seconds) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27556587/719212) before showing keyboard with above code, it can work well. 
Don't know the root cause of my project, but it works.
And it only happens on ios 11.

Answer (score 5):

When the TextField is not yet being drawn on the screen, then becomeFirstResponder() will not work. For example when it was hidden and never drawn. Then you need to call becomeFirstResponder() after it has been drawn. Maybe this will help:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    tf.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have created a new project and tried your code. It works normally on both simulator and device iOS11. Keyboard is showed and notification is called. This is the code i have tried.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                               name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                             object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  UITextField* tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
  tf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
  tf.text = @"test";

  [self.view addSubview:tf];
  if ([tf canBecomeFirstResponder]) {
    [tf becomeFirstResponder];  // surely this line is called
  }
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)note {
  NSDictionary* userInfo = [note userInfo];
  CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

  NSLog(@"Keyboard Height: %f Width: %f", kbSize.height, kbSize.width);
}

@end
```

You should check `DLog` method. I think keyboard's notification is called but nothing is logged because of `DLog` method.

Comment: I already run debug, not just log. And `keyboardWillShow` is only called when I click on UITextField to force keyboard showing. Does keyboard always show on your side without touch on text field?

Comment: Keyboard always show on both simulator and device when I check. You can see it here https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohjUUSFCXvimPR7l6/giphy.gif

Comment: thank you. It can work when I create new project with above code. There is something wrong with my other codes in view controller

Comment: Great answer! I'd like to add for others that the user properly used "becomeFirstResponder" in viewDidAppear. If, for example, you use "becomeFirstResponder" in viewWillAppear, then canBecomeFirstResponder will likely return false if the view has not yet been added to the view hierarchy. You are guaranteed that it has been added to the view hierarchy in viewDidLoad, but putting "canBecomeFirstResponder" in viewDidAppear I think (might be wrong) ensures that the observers are added as well (I had an issue with observers in viewDidLoad).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. I feel textField object is getting null in completion block and your calling `becomeFirstResponder` on that.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 215, 30)];
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textField.placeholder = @"Enter text to search";
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
textField.delegate = self;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.navigationBar
              duration:0.55f
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
            animations:^{
                self.navigationItem.titleView = textField;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [((UITextField *)self.navigationItem.titleView) becomeFirstResponder];
            }];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
        CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

}
```

Comment: i tried this. the problem is keyboard doesn't show, so the notification not work. it can only work when i click on textfield

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was, that I had 2 `UIWindow` objects and the one I used to add UI elements was not set as key window, and keyboard window had lower level, so keyboard was covered by my other window. I just had to call `makeKeyAndVisible()` on the second window. [john07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218798/john07)'s comment helped me figure this out. For further reference check: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1813/_index.html